# For each inside other for each on view MVC PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, foreach

I'm trying to give structure to my code and i am facing a problem.
I'm looping through a sql query response and for each element i'm trying to retrieve other related elements. It works in my controller without problem but when i'm trying to repeat in the view I always get the same value for the related element

My controller:

```
<?php
include_once('class/guide.class.php');
    $bdd = new DBHandler();
    $req = guide::getGuides($bdd,0,5);


foreach ($req as $results => $poi)
{
    $req[$results]['id'] = htmlspecialchars($poi['id']);;
    $req[$results]['name'] = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($poi['name'])); 

    $guide = new guide($results['name'],$bdd);
    $guidePois = $guide->getGuidePois($poi['id']);
    foreach ($guidePois as $res => $re)
    {
        echo $guidePois[$res]['id'];
        echo $guidePois[$res]['name'];
        $guidePois[$res]['id'] = htmlspecialchars($re['id']);
        $guidePois[$res]['name'] = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($re['name']));    
    }
}

include_once('listing.php');
```

here, you see that I echo the ids/names of the related list of element and it works well, the output is correct for each element of the first list.

When i do it in my view:

```
<?php
foreach($req as $poi)
{
?>
<div class="news">
    <h3>
        <?php echo $poi['id']; ?>
        <em>: <?php echo $poi['name']; ?></em>
    </h3>
    <?php foreach($guidePois as $re)
    { 
        ?>
        <h4>
        <?php echo $re['id']; ?>:
        <?php echo $re['name']; ?>
        </h4>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Somehow the first list output are the good elements, but for the 2nd list, i always get the related elements of the first item.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Perhaps something to do with `$re` not being the same thing as `$res` ?

Comment: I made this mistake after modifying a few times each variable before posting here, but unfortunately if i put <?php foreach($guidePois as $re), same problem happens, i edited my question !

Comment: Can you post how the Controller invokes the View?  Hard to debug with partial code.

Comment: I modified to show the full controller

Comment: add `echo '<pre>' . print_r($guidPois, TRUE) . '</pre>';` after `$guidePois = $guide->getGuidePois($poi['id']);` in your controller and before `<?php foreach($guidePois as $re)` in your view....do they output the same thing?

Comment: @TimAagaard : in the controller, the good values appear, in the view, it's always the related value of the first item

Comment: @GuillaumeWagner check out the answer:  you just missed to set $guidePois in each iteration of the view, so it was using the original value first set in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you only set:

```
$guidePois = $guide->getGuidePois($poi['id']);
```

once in the controller.

If you want it to work in the view, you need to insert this code right after the closing `</h3>`

```
<?php $guidePois = $guide->getGuidePois($poi['id']); ?>
```

So that $guidePois gets a new value in each iteration.

Complete view code:

```
<?php
foreach($req as $poi)
{
?>
<div class="news">
    <h3>
        <?php echo $poi['id']; ?>
        <em>: <?php echo $poi['name']; ?></em>
    </h3>
    <?php 
    $guidePois = $guide->getGuidePois($poi['id']);
    foreach($guidePois as $re)
    { 
        ?>
        <h4>
        <?php echo $re['id']; ?>:
        <?php echo $re['name']; ?>
        </h4>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: As a general note: 
why are you calling a query for each sub-item in the loop? 
That runs exponentially more queries on your DB server, than if you joined the data initially when you call: 
`$req = guide::getGuides($bdd,0,5);`

Also, have you seen the newer template tools available from PHP frameworks, for example Blade templates in Laravel? Makes for much cleaner code not having to use < ? php tags & echo all the time...

Comment: Hi tech, thanks for your answer. I was just trying to refresh my basic php knowledge with this project and now I will start over with Symfony.